# Marketing Cloud SAP & Community DNS Setup including transition period

Tags: marketing-cloud, community

Hi Marketing Cloud Gurus

I am working on an enterprise client's Marketing Cloud and Community Cloud setup.

They have an existing website and custom made portal and send emails from their own server and from Hubspot.

During the initial MC/Community setup and during the transition the existing website, portal and Hubspot platforms need to continue to function without modification.

They don't use the domain for corporate communications and we want to use the root domain, not a subdomain, for the MC SAP for email sending. For Community setup we will use a subdomain such as www2. during setup and then when ready to go live transition to root domain and www.

For Cloud Pages we can use cloud.clientsdomain.com

My questions are: 
1. can this be achieved, technically?
2. are there any reasons this solution is not optimal?

Kind Regards

Matt

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge yes - but not as a part of default SAP setup.

Salesforce states that the domain used for SAP configuration needs to be a new one that has not been used for websites and/or Emails previously.

Documentation Link - [**Sender Authentication Package Domain Requirements**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000248048&type=1)

> SAP requires a domain or sub-domain (selected by your company) for
>   **exclusive use** by Salesforce and should not be already used for
>   existing web pages or emails.

That being said, you can purchase a [**Private Domain**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000240073&language=en_US&type=1) SKU (it's cheap) for Marketing Cloud, and with that, you can use your official company domain just fine for Email sends.

Though it's important to know that links and images will always be wrapped through the SAP domain and you will not be able to use a single Private Domain for Email Sends + Cloud Pages at the same time.

To properly set up a Private Domain for Marketing Cloud you will need to work with their internal IT *and* Salesforce Deliverability Team to make sure DKIM, SPF, Sender ID and Domain Keys are properly configured, otherwise there will be issues with deliverability and IP reputation will take a hit.

You'll find some more information from [**Private Domain vs SAP**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231487&type=1) article.

Comment: Maybe a shortened version: It is step 4 of the [SAP configuration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000248048&type=1) You will need to contact salesforce support which will create a zone file for you which you then have to pass to the internal IT-Team of your customer. They need to change the DKIM, SPF, Sender ID and Domain Keys like Rain said. The zone file includes some settings you should consider not to use (for example all emails are send over the salesforce IP, even the normal ones). And clashes can occur when your client alrdy uses subdomains like images., cloud., click., ...

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, I think we have a clear path forward. One consideration I would appreciate your thoughts on is the ability to use a temporary subdomain during the transition i.e. v2.clientdomain.com and then use the root domain clientdomain.com after go live. Is it possible to reconfigure SAP settings later on?

Comment: You could do that but it requires you to do some initial stuff twice. For example your sends will be done from the mta record that you have defined in your dns records. that particular ip is a salesforce ip where your mails will be sent from. You need to do a slow start of email sends that your reputation does not get a huge blow, called IP Warm Up. Furthermore you have to change your dns records twice and other stuff like this. But as far as i know it is possible to reconfigure a SAP (it has to be, when you change domains etc.) It is also reconfigured when you do an SSL setup for links/images

Comment: Because i am not 100% certain that is completely changeable i would raise a support case and ask the salesforce support.